# Compiling half float neon instructions for iOS

Tags: c, xcode, arm, neon

The issue I am having is with some neon instructions which I believe are supported on the arm7 architecture. I am using the default compiler (Apple LLVM 5.0), it recognises other neon instructions although it does not like the half-float instruction.

Here is the code:

```
vcvt.f32.f16, q0, d1
```

This has compiled on gcc although the apple compiler does not like this instruction and gives the error: Instruction requires: half-float

Is there a compiler flag I can give to XCode? I can't find out how to enable the half float instructions googling around.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `-mfpu=neon-fp16`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The half-float format is actually not supported on all ARM v7 implementations.  See the [ARM manual here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/CIHJEBCE.html). It's required by vfp4, so if your chip supports that, that's a good start. In general I would recommend using run-time detection and dispatching.  To enable the instruction in general, you would need to use one of several floating point support options, in general "fp16" is the keyword, for example:

`-mfpu=neon-fp16` if you are sure that your target supports it for neon.  I couldn't find all of the examples for llvm either, but I think they are generally compatible with the GCC options, found in the [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options).